# How to diagnose a HTTP request being services by the wrong servlet in Wildfly?

Tags: servlets, wildfly

My underlying issue is: A HTTP request gets serviced by the default servlet instead of the one I'm expecting.
Logging gives me information like this during server start

```
WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /some/path
```

and still, `curl -i http://localhost/some/path` doesn't end up in my servlet, but returns HTTP 302, redirecting to `/some/path/`, which then gets served by Undertow's DefaultServlet. So how would I diagnose this type of issue?

Is there a way to see all deployed servlets in a Wildfly with their deployment info?
Is the Admin Console any good and if so, how?

Comment: Can you show your servlet mapping?

Comment: Dang. That's the problem. The servlet mapping had a URL pattern like *.xyz, so a correct URL like /some/path/test.xyz is actually serviced by "my" servlet. Thanks for asking the right question. I'll delete my question in a bit.

Comment: Although the question somewhat remains - is it possible to see the servlet mapping in the running server, without looking at web.xml?